# Fix Embed Video Code of Ooyala

Tags: video, ooyala

I am Using Wordpress with Custom Built theme.

I have options to select post formats like audio , video , quote etc.

When i select my post as Video , it shows two options Video URL, Video Embed Code.

In video Embed Code if i put Embed Code from Youtube it works. But main problem is i upload my videos on Ooyala.com. and when i insert my html embed code from ooyala. it doesn't display video it just displays code.( no Video)

After going through my code of theme, i came across this code which converts the embed code like

```
function wpbandit_video_wmode_transparent($html, $url, $attr) {
if ( strpos( $html, "<embed src=" ) !== false ) {
    $html = str_replace('</param><embed', '</param><param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param><embed wmode="opaque" ', $html);
} elseif ( strpos ($html, 'feature=oembed') !== false ) {
    $html = str_replace('feature=oembed', 'feature=oembed&wmode=opaque', $html);
} 
    return $html;
}
    add_filter('embed_oembed_html','wpbandit_video_wmode_transparent',10,3);

/**
    Add container to default video embeds
**/
function wpbandit_embed_oembed_html($html, $url, $attr, $post_id) {
    return '<div class="video-container">' . $html . '</div>';
}
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'wpbandit_embed_oembed_html', 99, 4);
```

And the Code i got from ooyala as my video embed code is like this:

```
<script src='https://player.ooyala.com/v3/84b6e4bac6d945439a38bdfff895a0fd'></script>    <div id='ooyalaplayer' style='width:1280px;height:720px'></div><script>OO.ready(function() {     OO.Player.create('ooyalaplayer', 'N5MG1rYTpsId-Q4ZlUy1JEykqD5QMWEN'); });</script><noscript>    <div>Please enable Javascript to watch this video</div></noscript>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing our Wordpress plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ooyala-video-browser/